# How wide should the distance between my elbows be for the zercher squat?

Tags: squats

It seems so you can go as wide as you want in the elbow distance provided that you make the distance between your feet as wide as possible. So, what is the ideal width between elbows? I find keeping it shoulder width makes my stance go a bit wide... and I am not sure if that is good..?

Answer (score 1):

"Ideal" would be the width that allows your upper back to keep in extension, shoulders externally rotated, scapulas back. Too narrow would cause your upper back to go into flexion, robbing you of one of the key benefits of the zercher squat - upper back stability.

Wider stance is perfectly fine for squats, joint health-wise, assuming you keep your knees out and don't let them fall inwards towards each other.

Comment: Your shoulders are not going to be externally rotated in a Zercher squat. External shoulder rotation, in that arm position, would mean trying to touch the back of your hands to the barbell plates, whereas Zercher squats are more often done with shoulders internally rotated, such that the hands can be linked together.

Comment: They can be done with external rotation, or at least attempting external rotation. I did zerchers with linked arms initially, moved on to wider arm position, big difference in upper back engagement.